# group by to create multiple files

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have written a code using pandas groupby and its is working.
my question is how can I save each group in a excel sheet.
For example is you have group of fruits [ 'apple', 'grapes',.....'mango
']
I want to save apple in an excel and gapes in a different excel

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C://Desktop/test/file.xlsx')
g = df.groupby('fruits')
for fruits, fruits_g in g:
        print(fruits)
        print(fruits_g)
```

```
Mango 
  name   id   purchase   fruits
1  john  877          2  Mango 

apple
  name   id   purchase  fruits
0   ram  654          5  apple
3  Sam   546          5  apple

BlueB
   name   id   purchase   fruits
7  david  767          9  black 

grapes
  name   id   purchase   fruits
2  Dan   454          1  grapes
4   sys  890          7  grapes

mango
  name   id   purchase  fruits
5  baka  786          6  mango

strawB
    name   id   purchase  fruits
6  silver  887          9  straw
```

How Can i Create an excel for each group of fruit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple", "orange"],
    "Name": ["John", "Sam", "David", "Rebeca", "Sydney"],
    "ID": [877, 546, 767, 887, 890],
    "Purchase": [1, 2, 5, 6, 4]
})

grouped = df.groupby("Fruit")

# run this to generate separate Excel files
for fruit, group in grouped:
    group.to_excel(excel_writer=f"{fruit}.xlsx", sheet_name=fruit, index=False)

# run this to generate a single Excel file with separate sheets
with pd.ExcelWriter("fruits.xlsx") as writer:
    for fruit, group in grouped:
        group.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name=fruit, index=False)
```

Comment: Hello Clade, I did try your solution, but its not generating any files. Can you please help.

Comment: Odd, I just ran it again and it worked for me. I am using Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.25.0. The files are saved to the same directory as the script—perhaps you are looking in the wrong place? Another possibility is that you did not change the groupby column from "Fruit" to "fruits" to match your example.

Comment: Thank you Clade! It's working. If you dint mine can you please can you explain to me this code (excel_writer=f"{fruit}) I want to learn and I am trying to improve your code by adding Destination folder to save all the file at one place. I did try to do it by my self but I couldn't figure it out can you please help me. I am so sorry to ask you too much help. I am pretty new to Python, Thank you once again for helping me.

Comment: `excel_writer` is a parameter of `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` that takes the file path of the output Excel file. Since, in my first solution, each loop generates a new file with a different name, I use an f-string (new to 3.6) which converts the content of the brackets to a string and joins it with whatever is inside the string literal. It is the same result as if I wrote `excel_writer=fruit+".xlsx"`.

Comment: In order to store all of your files in a separate folder you must write the relative path to a sub-directory `excel_writer=f"Fruit_Folder/{fruit}.xlsx"` or the absolute path to another directory `excel_writer=f"C:/Documents/Fruit_Folder/{fruit}.xlsx"`.

Comment: Thank You for helping me Clade! You have changed my life